# i can't make check box that can select all with flutter using getx

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

i tried many ways to make it but it does'nt work, which i don't understand is the cheack box i made it work because setstate but what i learned is Getx don't have to use setstate but when i delete it check box doesn't change

The homePagectrl

```
class HomePageCtrl extends GetxController {

bool isdone = false;
List tasks = [];
bool ischeacked = false;

void checkAll() {
for (var i = 0; i \< c.tasks.

length; i++) {
c.tasks\[i\].isdone = true;
}
update();
}
}
```

the test page

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State\<Test\> createState() =\> \_TestState();
}

HomePageCtrl c = Get.find();

class \_TestState extends State\<Test\> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: const Text('test'),
),
body: GetBuilder\<HomePageCtrl\>(
init: HomePageCtrl(),
builder: (controller) =\> Center(
child: Column(children: \[
Checkbox(
value: c.ischeacked,
onChanged: (val) {
setState(() {
c.ischeacked = val!;
});
}),
Checkbox(
value: c.isdone,
onChanged: (val) {
setState(() {
c.isdone = val!;
});
}),
SizedBox(
height: 50,
),
ListTile(
enabled: true,
leading: Icon(Icons.check_box),
onTap: () {
setState(() {
controller.cheackAll();

                  });
                },
                title: Text("cheack all"),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ));

}
}

void cheackAll(BuildContext context) {
c.checkAll();
c.update();
}
```

i tryed some of things but it did'nt work

Comment: thanks for the advice , should i use provider as the best recomendation

Comment: Remi is putting no new effort into the Provider package. RiverPod is getting all the cool stuff, and does everything Provider did, and more.

Comment: @Anas3Ezz Did you fix the issue?